# Comma as decimal separator Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have numeric data with comma as decimal separator for example my data looks like

```
Number 
1,2
2,1
1
1,5
3
4
```

I want the output to be

```
Number 
1.2
2.1
1
1.5
3
4
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the dtype of that column?  And what have you tried / researched on your own?

Comment: pd.read_csv( '  ',decimal="," )